# DOM innerText keeps showing just the last element of an array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
fruitsButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    fruitsArray.forEach((fruit) => {
        newParagraph.innerText = `I'll buy a ${fruit} next year `;
        screenToShow.append(newParagraph);
    });
});
```

I want my code to loop each individual element and show the text but when i try doing it keeps showing just the last element of the array, i tried to using the console and it works but on DOM it does not really work so pls help

Comment: ```newParagraph.innerText += `I'll buy a ${fruit} next year  ```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `newParagraph` every time, replacing the current innerText instead of adding a new paragraph.

You can create a new `p` element for every fruit in the loop:

```js
const screenToShow = document.getElementById('screen')
const fruitsArray = ['apple', 'banana', 'cranberry']

fruitsArray.forEach(fruit => {
  const newParagraph = document.createElement('p')
  newParagraph.innerText = `I'll buy a ${fruit} next year`
  screenToShow.append(newParagraph)
})
```

```html
<div id='screen'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

newParagraph.innerText += `I'll buy a ${fruit} next year` 
Add += to append multiple elements see my addition above